FluxCD - Technology autodetection
Just a simple question.
In ArgoCD I can point to a directory and it automatically detects weather I use kustomize or helm or even simple kubernetes manifests.
Can Flux autodetect as ArgoCD does which technology is used for applying the manifests?
